# Tabhost framelayout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-framelayout

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/above_root"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#191919"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:id="@+id/horizontalscrollview"
                android:scrollbars="none" >
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                //ANOTHER WIDGET
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want have a view like this:

```
 |   T   A   B    S  |
 *********************
 |FRAME |   ANOTHER  |
 |LAYOUT|    VIEW    |
 *********************
```

But when I run project, Framelayout take whole of view below tabs.
How can I solve that?

Thanks in advance.